# How to mock ActivatedRoute in Angular without using TestBed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular-activatedroute

The question is pretty simple. I have never really liked how the original testing works in Angular (the `TestBed` part), so I have always done it the classic way: mocking with *ts-mockito*. No `TestBed`, no configuration needed, zero confusion. I even use Jest instead of Karma/Jasmine.

But when it came to mocking the `ActivatedRouter`, I always had trouble, as I guess a lot of you out there. One solution I've seen is having an object with the enormous amounts of properties that `ActivatedRouter` has, and substituting the value of the property you want to mock. That solution is pretty annoying, and quite unsustainable.

The other solution is being forced to use `TestBed`, which I dont really like, and do the following:

```js
providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              paramMap: {
                get: () => 'foo'
              },
              queryParamMap: {
                get: () => 'bar'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

This one is actually pretty good, but as I say it forces you to use `TestBed`. So, how can you mock `ActivatedRoute` behaviour without using `TestBed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, today I figured out a way to mock it in a nice way **without** having to use `TestBed`.

This would be a small example of how a complete test would be using *ts-mockito*:

```js
function setup() {
  const route = mock(ActivatedRoute);
  const routeInstance = instance(route);
  Object.defineProperty(routeInstance, 'snapshot', {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: {
      paramMap: {
        get: () => 'someParam'
      },
      queryParamMap: {
        get: () => 'someQueryParam'
      }
    }
  });

  return {
    sut: new MyComponent(routeInstance),
    route
  };
}

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should get param and query param from activated route', async () => {
    const { sut, route } = setup();

    const actualParam = sut.getParam();
    expect(actualParam).toBe('someParam');

    const actualQueryParam = sut.getQueryParam();
    expect(actualQueryParam).toBe('someQueryParam');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. I was struggling with mocking the paramMap property and failed a bunch of times until your post gave me the insight I needed.